# fastshap::explain() returning error 'number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length'

Tags: r

I'm trying to use fastshap::explain() to understand the feature importance for N clusters in a probability forest.

I set up the model like so:

```
X <- df %>% 
  dplyr::select(-c(var1, var15, var29, var30, var31, clusters)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, as.factor) %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.numeric)

Y <- df %>% pull(clusters)

p_forest <- grf::probability_forest(
  X = X,
  Y = Y)

# Set up function 
pfun <- function(object, newdata) {
  grf:::predict.probability_forest(object = object, newdata = newdata)$predictions
}

# Set up parallel backend
cl <- if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix") 8 else makeCluster(32)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# Run some simulations
system.time({  # estimate run time
  set.seed(5038)
  shap_vals <- fastshap::explain(p_forest,
                       X = X,
                       pred_wrapper = pfun,
                       adjust = TRUE,
                       nsim = 10,
                       .parallel = TRUE
                       )
})
```

And I receive the following error:

```
Warning message in err * (v - (v * sum(v))/(1 + sum(v))):
“longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length”
Warning message in res[, 1L] + adj:
“longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length”
Error in res[, 1L] <- res[, 1L] + adj: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
Error in res[, 1L] <- res[, 1L] + adj: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
Traceback:
1. system.time({
 .     set.seed(5038)
 .     shap_vals <- explain(p_forest, X = X, pred_wrapper = pfun, 
 .         adjust = TRUE, nsim = 10, .parallel = TRUE)
 . })
2. explain(p_forest, X = X, pred_wrapper = pfun, adjust = TRUE, 
 .     nsim = 10, .parallel = TRUE)   # at line 13-19 of file <text>
3. explain.default(p_forest, X = X, pred_wrapper = pfun, adjust = TRUE, 
 .     nsim = 10, .parallel = TRUE)
Timing stopped at: 1.235e+04 105.8 483.4
```

Does anyone know where i'm going wrong here? And how to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to be honest. the dataset I actually feed in to the probability forest is massive and while I could _attempt_ to construct something that generates the same error, I don't know at a fundamental level what the error is telling me about the data so i wouldn't really know where to start in terms of making some fake data that replicates the problem

Comment: Perhaps you can check for missing values etc as i haven't used this package before

Comment: Ok, thank you. I don't have any missing values as i've used multiple imputation to fill in any gaps

Comment: ok, then an option would be to check the data format in the example page of `?explain` and see if there is any difference with that data compared to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the output of the line:

```
grf:::predict.probability_forest(object = object, newdata = newdata)$predictions
```

was a matrix where explain() expected a vector. I was able to solve it by indexing the predictions like so:

```
grf:::predict.probability_forest(object = object, newdata = newdata)$predictions[,1]
```

And then repeating for each cluster's set of predictions